# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' to type 'BugTrackingSystem.BugDescriptor'

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm the beginner in C# and doing my project I have some trouble. I've got `DataGrid` in Windows Form, which is connected to database. To edit record in database I must select this on datagrid. I wrote code for selection, here it is.

```
public BugDescriptor GetSelectedBug()
{
    BugDescriptor selectedBug = null;

    if (ctlBugs.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        selectedBug = (BugDescriptor) ctlBugs.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
    }
    if (ctlBugs.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
    {
        selectedBug = (BugDescriptor) ctlBugs.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.DataBoundItem;
    }

    return selectedBug;
}
```

So, `ctlBugs` is the name of my datagrid, `BugDescriptor` is the class, descripting fields of the record in database. 
When I try to debug this I have an exception: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Bug_ED6497CD7603C9E48A4F28CF92AF30E4A88B104DE0AC6FAF0D12F034495FF727' to type 'BugTrackingSystem.BugDescriptor`.

What I'm doing wrong? Ask me, if I need to tell someting else about my code.

P. S. I've already read some answers to similar questions but couldn't understand how to use them in my trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the object in `DataBoundItem` is of type `Bug` not `BugDescriptor`.  Hopefully that makes sense on your context.

Entity Framework to track state dynamically generates proxy classes that extend your entity classes. That is why you see a strange class name on the exception, but the original class name is part of the name.  Also on VS you can inspect the object to find the base class.

System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.**Bug**_ED6497CD7603C9E48A4F28CF92AF30E4A88B104DE0AC6FAF0D12F034495FF727

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I could not find how to inspect the object in DataBoundItem?

Comment: In Visual Studio, just put a break-point in `GetSelectedBug` and step through the code with the 'Autos' debugger window open.  [Viewing Data in the Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esta7c62.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable DynamicProxies:

```
dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

In EF 4

```
objectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

But you will need to call "include" when using linq.